# In Chrome, if there is a duplicate hover () in the jquery, only one applies

Tags: jquery, css, hover

```
jQuery( document ).ready(
 function($) {
      $('.ppro').hover(
        function () {
            $('#pronav ul').css("height", "25px");
        },
        function () {
            $('#pronav ul').css("height", "0px");
        }
    );

    $('.pproj').hover(
        function () {
            $('#pronav ul').css("height", "50px");
        },
        function () {
            $('#pronav ul').css("height", "0px");
        }
    );
  });
```

This is my jquery.

```
<div class="product-menu-bar-contrain">
 <nav id="pronav">
  <ul>
   <li class = "ppro">~~~~~</li>
   <li class = "pproj">~~~~~</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

And this is my HTML code.

Raising the cursor to ppro changes the height to 25px. However, the height does not change when I place the cursor on pproj. It works fine in IE, but Chrome is having problems.

```
.pproj:hover a {
    color : #f2b221;
}
```

This CSS code works fine on both IE and Chrome.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but it works fine for me on Chrome [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqvLvbn0/)